# Django-Allauth Connect with Facebook but Force Username Change

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I'm using Django-Allauth to successfully log in with my Facebook account on my webserver. The problem is, when I use the default SignUpView to do so, the username stored in the DB is the username Facebook returns from the social login. Something like this:

```
<firstname>.<lastname>.<integer>
```

I've figured out how to connect my Facebook account with an already created standard user account ( not social ) at a later time using the view at:

```
/accounts/social/connections/
```

And how to change emails with

```
/accounts/email/
```

Can someone please show me how I can force a user to pick a non-facebook username when they log in with Facebook on my site without first creating a standard user?

Thanks!

============ EDIT =======================

So adding this to settings.py prompts for username and password to associate with facebook login, but does not prompty for a password:

```
SOCIALACCOUNT_AUTO_SIGNUP = False
```

I still need to figure out how to prompt for a password in this state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixes it - inherit from SignupForm for social auth signup form.

```
class SignupForm(SignupForm):
```